# Testing web pages using Java

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests

I am looking for java tests that I can use in automation testing of web pages hosted locally.

These are for RESTful web services.

The situation is we have some web pages or web service hosted locally and I need to run several tests on this.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)? You can use it to drive a web browser to browse through your pages. You can use Java code to make assertions about what the page looks like after you do certain things (click a button, type some text, etc).

Comment: I got it, selenium to generate tests that i can use in automation and soapUI to develop tests for Restful services, but is there any ready-made solutions that i can download and try to run in my automation?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium for webpages, [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html) for RESTful web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL class in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

I feel that you don't need to use Selenium as the REST calls you will be making are independent of the browser. You don't need an actual browser to make these calls. If you do that, your automation will run a lot faster.

If you also have an authentication and authorization service then you will need to take care of it using the Set-Cookie HTTP header.